# "ReferenceError: DetectFlashVer is not defined" when using a proxy

Tags: javascript, php, flash, nginx

I'm trying to serve a flash file via nginx proxy, but it fails with said error `ReferenceError: DetectFlashVer is not defined`. I had the same result using a simple PHP proxy (https://github.com/joshdick/miniProxy). Any ideas on what could fix it?

The line in reference:
`var hasProductInstalled = DetectFlashVer(6, 0, 65);`

The page's code:

```
<base href='myDomain'/>

<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />

<!--  load bunch of scripts -->
<script src='AC_OETags.js' language='javascript'></script>    
<script src='history/history.js' language='javascript'></script>


<style>
body { margin: 0px; overflow:hidden }
</style>
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
<!--
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Globals
// Major version of Flash required
var requiredMajorVersion = 10;
// Minor version of Flash required
var requiredMinorVersion = 1;
// Minor version of Flash required
var requiredRevision = 0;
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// -->
</script>
</head>

<body scroll='no' bgcolor='#000000'>
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
// Version check for the Flash Player that has the ability to start Player Product Install (6.0r65)

var hasProductInstall = DetectFlashVer(6, 0, 65);

// Version check based upon the values defined in globals

var hasRequestedVersion = DetectFlashVer(requiredMajorVersion, requiredMinorVersion, requiredRevision);
```

Comment: How did you determine that the proxy is the problem? Does it work fine when you request the page directly?

Comment: It's a flash file, but yes, it worked without it.

Comment: Well, the flash file won't work by itself I think, since you're referencing JavaScript code. Usually this is the result of incorrect JavaScript merging (ordering), but this is quite hard to debug without having a look at the page that uses the flash file. The shot in the dark is that you're not passing the hostname to the backend (`proxy_set_header Host $host;`).

Comment: It is passed (the line is present).

What do you want to know about the page? I've added some info to the question.